# k distinct combination of size p without replacement

Tags: matlab, random, numbers, combinations

From the integers `1,...,N` I would like to take k random distinct combinations without repetition of size `p`. For example, if `N=10`, `k=4` and `p=3`, a possible outcome would be:

```
1 4 9
9 4 2
3 5 2
1 8 4
```

But not:

```
1 4 9
9 4 2
3 5 3
1 9 4
```

For two reasons:

1. `[1 4 9]` and `[1 9 4]` are the same combination.
2. `[3 5 3]` is not without repetition.

Note that getting all possible combinations and the (randomly) picking `k` of them easily runs into memory problems.

Comment: The reason I edited those first two words out is because it's contained within the tag. That's what tags are for. Secondly: at least write it like "MATLAB", as the MathWorks called their program if you insist on keeping it there.

Comment: Yes well my experience is that even though it's in the tags, explicitly writing Matlab, or as you wish MATLAB, makes people even more aware of it. That is why I put it back in. I didn't know that was such a crime, seeing as someone else took it out again...

Comment: It's not a crime, it's just superfluous. People usually browse by language tag, thus end up at this question through the MATLAB-tag. SO tends to keep its questions as short and to the point as possible, so future users can find the desired information as fast as possible; that's also why I edited out the first paragraph. The reason Ander edited it out again, is probably because even though it's not very unusual or superfluous to put the language name there, the bold formatting made it stand out for no apparent reason.

Comment: @EricSchols it's not a criminal offence, but using boldface and the worst spelling of MATLAB(/matlab for me) together easily hits the threshold of some people:) I'm sure no offense was meant, take it as a friendly advice (you'll see that there are a *lot* of editors who change much less reasonable stuff in the posts of others.)

Comment: Okay, thank you both.

Comment: @AndrasDeak, what about MaTLaB?    XD

Comment: @EricSchols now **that**'s a crime.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I have found a solution that works for me. My main concerns were:

- I want the `k` combinations to be random.
- processing time.

The below function samples a single random combination of size `p`, (namely `row = randperm(N,p)`) each iteration and adds that combination if it isn't already present.

Of the three parameters, mainly `k` influences the processing time. For not too large `k`, this codes runs in matters of seconds. The most extreme case I myself will encounter is `N = 10^6, k = 2000, p = 10` and it still runs in 1 second.

I hope this also helps other people, as I've come across this question on multiple sites, without a satisfactory answer.

```
function C = kcombsn(N,k,p)
    C       = randperm(N,p);
    Csort   = sort(C,2);

    while size(C,1) < k

        row = randperm(N,p);
        row_sort = sort(row);

        if isempty(intersect(row_sort,Csort,'rows'))
            C = [C; row];
            Csort = [Csort; row_sort];
        end
    end

end
```

**Edit:**
I also [posted the code on the MATLAB File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54876-kcombsn).